# pandas: combine two index columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Series:

```
data = {(pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), datetime.time(0, 0)): 6.885,
        (pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), datetime.time(0, 5)): 6.363, 
        (pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), datetime.time(0, 10)): 6.093,
        (pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), datetime.time(0, 15)): 6.768, 
        (pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), datetime.time(0, 20)): 7.11}
s = pd.Series(data)

2016-01-01  00:00:00    6.885
            00:05:00    6.363
            00:10:00    6.093
            00:15:00    6.768
            00:20:00    7.110
dtype: float64
```

How can I combine the two index columns to create a `DatetimeIndex` like so:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00    6.885
2016-01-01 00:05:00    6.363
2016-01-01 00:10:00    6.093
2016-01-01 00:15:00    6.768
2016-01-01 00:20:00    7.110
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Intuitive Answer**
Use `pd.Index.map` and `pd.Timedelta`

```
s.index = s.index.map(lambda t: t[0] + pd.Timedelta(str(t[1])))
s

2016-01-01 00:00:00    6.885
2016-01-01 00:05:00    6.363
2016-01-01 00:10:00    6.093
2016-01-01 00:15:00    6.768
2016-01-01 00:20:00    7.110
dtype: float64
```

---

**Fast Answer**
If speed is what your after, try this

```
t = np.array(
    [t.hour * 60 + t.minute for t in s.index.get_level_values(1)],
    'timedelta64[m]'
)

s.index = s.index.get_level_values(0) + t

2016-01-01 00:00:00    6.885
2016-01-01 00:05:00    6.363
2016-01-01 00:10:00    6.093
2016-01-01 00:15:00    6.768
2016-01-01 00:20:00    7.110
dtype: float64
```

---

## Time Testing

Please note that this is **only** if you care about optimization.  Otherwise, please use what you think the right choice is for you.

```
jez = lambda s: s.index.get_level_values(0) + pd.to_timedelta(s.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str))
pir1 = lambda s: s.index.map(lambda t: t[0] + pd.Timedelta(str(t[1])))
pir2 = lambda s: s.index.get_level_values(0) + np.array([t.hour * 60 + t.minute for t in s.index.get_level_values(1)], 'timedelta64[m]')

res = pd.DataFrame(
    np.nan, [10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    'jez pir1 pir2'.split()
)

for i in res.index:
    s_ = pd.concat([s] * i)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = f'{j}(s_)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import {j}, s_'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)

res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0)

             jez       pir1  pir2
10      2.400808   3.530032   1.0
30      4.045287   8.378484   1.0
100     6.337601  18.610263   1.0
300     8.664829  30.363422   1.0
1000   11.593935  44.210358   1.0
3000   11.899037  47.425953   1.0
10000  12.226166  49.546467   1.0
30000  12.543602  50.730653   1.0
```

Comment: I adore your time testing approach :-)

Comment: @piRSquared - In my opinion `np.array([t.hour * 3600 + t.minute * 60 + t.second for t in s.index.get_level_values(1)],'timedelta64[s]')` should be better, because more general.

Answer (score 4):

Convert second value of `MultiIndex` to [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add to first level:

```
s.index=s.index.get_level_values(0)+pd.to_timedelta(s.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str))
print (s)
2016-01-01 00:00:00    6.885
2016-01-01 00:05:00    6.363
2016-01-01 00:10:00    6.093
2016-01-01 00:15:00    6.768
2016-01-01 00:20:00    7.110
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```